# c# Clear listview from class by metho

Tags: class, listview, methods

Does someone know, how to use this code in class like method ? I cant use listView1 because its doesnt know it.

```
listView1.Items.Clear();


...





namespace WinForm
    {
        public class Delete 
        {


            public void clear()
            {
               ListView // know only list view but not listView1, ive set modifer to public.
            }

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Edit:
ok, i need to do my school project and thats what only left. in form i have just whole methods and just this one command " listView1.Items.Clear();" so im trying to do it by method ;-) so if i press button it will call the method to clear my listView1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass `listview1` as a parameter to the function.

```
public void clear(ListView listview)
            {
               listview.Items.Clear();
            }
```

or make `listview1` `static`

though it would be better if you can explain what you are trying to achieve. 
P.S: the method is not even static.

Comment: ok, i need to do my school project and thats what only left. in form i have just whole methods and just this one command " listView1.Items.Clear();" so im trying to do it by method ;-) so if i press button it will call the method to clear my listView1.

Comment: why do you need a separate class Delete ?

Comment: Because teacher told me that, and i have absolutly no idea how to do that. If i type this to my class it gives me an error"Error 1 No overload for method 'clear' takes 0 argument"

Comment: did you try to do as i said? passing the listview as a parameter?

Comment: how did you add elements to the list? using a separate class?

Comment: Yup i did it as parameter and i use separate class.

Comment: y cant you do the same for delete?